# Correctly handling enumerations coming from REST api calls in Typescript

Tags: typescript

We have a rest API that returns a String for a given field but we know that this String is in fact an enumeration which we have created in Typescript.

Our enumeration looks like so

```
 export enum Enum1 {
        RED = 'Red',
        GREEN = 'Green',
        BLUE = 'Blue'
 }
```

The problem we have is that the backend returns `RED` while when comparing Typescript uses `Red`, so the following comparison

```
myResp.myField === Enum1.RED
```

Doesn't work correctly. What is the appropriate way of handling this case in Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

Typescript will compare the value of the enum, not the name of the enum with the `myResp.myField`. At runtime the enum is transformed into an object that is initialized like so:

```
function (Enum1) {
    Enum1["RED"] = "Red";
    Enum1["GREEN"] = "Green";
    Enum1["BLUE"] = "Blue";
}
```

So when comparing with `Enum1. RED` you will be comparing with the value for the field, namely `'Red'`

The simplest solution is to set the values of the enum the same as the names

```
 export enum Enum1 {
        RED = 'RED',
        GREEN = 'GREEN',
        BLUE = 'BLUE '
 }
```

Comment: They would be horrible though when rendered on the ui, is there a better alternative?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 Depends what you are willing to change. You could change the test to `Object.keys(Enum1).includes(myResp.myField)`. Also changing the type of `myField` to not be an enum value but rather the key of the enum `myField : keyof typeof Enum1`

Comment: You should never use the index value of an enum for display purposes, i.e. either split it up into `RED= { value: 'RED', label:'Red'}` or map the enum indexes to labels in a separate object.